# How to count all values in array in Javascript if I am using Delete

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am doing a delete on index of an array. Since doing a delete like this:

```
delete arr[index];
```

Will delete the index but will not affect the index of an array, that is perfectly what I need on my functionality.

The problem that I am encountering is that its length is not changing:

```
console.log(arr.length);
```

Will return the same index as before. Is there a way to retrieve the actual number of values I have on my array if I did use the delete functionality?

Comment: if you don't have values that are falsey (0 etc).  Then you can do `arr.filter(Boolean).length`.

Comment: Perfect that is all that I need, you can post your comment so that I can mark it as an answer. :)

Comment: _"that its length is not changing"_ - And that's why using `delete` for an array is a bad idea...

Comment: Arrays don't work that way. Use filter or splice. Honestly the `delete` operator has almost zero actual use cases. It's just a foot-gun.

Comment: I understand that, I am just doing this for some testing purposes on my data, and will not intentionally used on any production sort of purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are certain that you don't have any falsey values.  Then, you can simply to this:

```
arr.filter(Boolean).length
```

However, you would need a better filter function to account for some values (like `0`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `splice` instead, in your case:

`arr.splice(index, 1);`

Try this:

```
let arr=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; //length 5
arr.splice(0, 1); //length 4
```

**Update**

If you want to preserve indexes inside array while knowing the actual number of values inside an array, I suggest you do a simple trick by maintaining a `counter` value:

```
delete arr[index];
counter--;
```

and instead of reading `arr.length` you can just use `counter`

Comment: The problem with splice is other index of array is changed. I don't want the index of other arrays to be changed.

Comment: So you want to know the actual length of the array while not affecting the index?

Comment: I want to remove specific index of an array and the index of other elements still remains the same. Afterward, will count all the values remaining.

Answer (score 1):

Yes but `delete` is partially work with array, It is mainly for object. you can use splice or filter for this

```
arr.splice(index, 1);
```

or if you want to strict with current solution then get length in this way.

```
var count  = a.filter(val=>val != '').length;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that [`delete` removes the item from an array but doesn't affect the length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Deleting_array_elements).

To get the *true* length, you can just count up all the non-empty elements in the array. Something as simple as this will work:

```
function getLengthWithoutEmptyElements (array) {
  return array.filter(() => true).length;
}

const arr = [0, 1, 2, 3];
delete arr[2];

console.log(arr.length) // 4, unchanged (bad)
console.log(getLengthWithoutEmptyElements(arr)) // 3, correct (good)
```

This works because while the `empty` element still appears to exist in your array, its actually not there anymore (all references to it was destroyed when you called `delete`).

So, if you filter the array and return true on every element that's *actually* in it, you'll get the array without the empty elements - so we can just get the length of that.

### Note

This approach of `array.filter(() => true).length` works on **all** inputs since it will *only* ignore `empty` values, which is good because you won't get wrong results by filtering out falsy values by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the index of the previous array you can filter it only as needed to get rid of **falsy values** as `undefined` and `null`

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
delete arr[1];
console.log(arr.filter(o => o).length);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am doing a delete on index of an array. Since doing a delete like this:
>
> `delete arr[index];`
>
> Will delete the index but will not affect the index of an array, that is perfectly what I need on my functionality.

"delete" changes the value of the element to **undefined** (https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_methods.asp), it does not actually delete an element.

If you do not have a problem with leaving **undefined** holes in your array you can count your elements that are not **undefined** but it is not a good way of doing things imo.

What you may want to do is to create an array of objects where you specify an index value when you add an element. Then you keep your custom index when removing an element of the array